# How do I convert to relative paths for image files in access (for using database from a flash drive)?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I would like to move my database to a flash drive (a catalogue for a fossil collection). I want to send it to some colleagues who might use it on different computers. The associated images come to quite a size, 22 GB, so given the hassle of repeated copying and not knowing how much space they have, I thought running it directly off a flash drive would be more convenient.

I have moved the images to the same folder as the database. These are stored in subfolders within a folder "Collection images".

I can display the images by putting (for example)

```
=[CurrentProject].[Path] & "\Collection images\Cabinet
19\0001-19-1-22390a-1.tif"
```

in the image control source but I already have the file paths (over a thousand) in a field and was wondering whether there was a less time-consuming way of doing this. I've also created a search form and I'm not sure how this method will affect its behaviour.

This is my first database and my coding experience is pretty much non-existent. A 'by-the-numbers' explanation would be very helpful but any pointers would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with _I already have the file paths in a field_? Do you just have a table, with that data in a table field? Or do you mean you have a form field?

Comment: I just have the paths in a table field 'imagePath'. On the original arrangement I have these formatted for absolute paths
 e.g. C:\Collection images\Cabinet 19\0001-19-1-22390a-1.tif" but I've since copied the database and the image folder to the same directory to try to make the relative paths work e.g. I gave an example of the relative path I was trying out in the image control source.

Comment: The images are displayed in a form - with various information regarding the specimen - and the image field in the form takes the path from the table field 'imagePath'. Sorry if I've got a bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

My personal approach often is: use a placeholder to indicate the path to the folder:

First, update the table:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ImagePath = Replace(ImagePath, "C:\My\Absolute\Path", "%Placeholder%")
```

And then, replace the placeholder with the current path when displaying.

As the image property:

```
=Replace(ImagePath, "%Placeholder%", CurrentProject.Path)
```

You can also decide to just store the relative path without a placeholder:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ImagePath = Replace(ImagePath, "C:\My\Absolute\Path", "")
```

And then append the current path at the start:

```
=CurrentProject.Path & ImagePath
```

The main advantage of the placeholder approach is that you can mix absolute paths and relative paths, and use multiple different relative paths in a single table.